# SqsMessageDrivenAdapter consume and publish to multiple queues, DLQ when publish to any queue fails

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

The flow :

1. Read from `Ingestion` Queue
2. Publish to `Queue One` and 'Queue Two' in parallel using a pub-sub channel
3. Aggregate Publish Result of `Queue One` and `Queue Two`
4. If publish to any one of `Queue One` and `Queue Two` fail, throw the exception to `SqsMessageDrivenAdapter` to trigger the NO_REDRIVE behavior. `Ingestion` queue has redrive of `maxReceiveCount=3`, post which the message is expected to be DLQ to `Ingestion-Dead-Letter`

Until step 4, everything works as expected. However at step 4, if `Queue One` does not exist, the aggregator completes but the exception is not thrown to the `SqsMessageDrivenAdapter`. I get this message.
I want this exception to propagate to `SqsMessageDrivenAdapter`, since I am not providing any `outputChannel` or `errorChannel` on the message handlers. I am a bit confused here.

```
2021-06-04 17:49:10.665  WARN 539 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.i.c.MessagePublishingErrorHandler    : Error message was not delivered.

Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
```

The Flow Config for the above 4 steps:

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class DispatchFlow {

    private final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs;

    @Bean
    public MessageProducer ingesionQueueConsumer() {
        SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
                new SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(amazonSqs, "ingestion");
        adapter.setVisibilityTimeout(15);
        adapter.setWaitTimeOut(10);
        adapter.setAutoStartup(true);
        adapter.setMaxNumberOfMessages(5);
        adapter.setOutputChannelName("sqsMultiDispatchChannel");
        adapter.setErrorChannelName("errorChannel");
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow queueOneDispatchFlow(MessageHandler publishToQueueOneHandler) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("sqsMultiDispatchChannel")
                .enrichHeaders(h-> h.header("errorChannel", "errorChannel"))
                .handle(publishToQueueOneHandler)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler publishToQueueOneHandler() {
        final SqsMessageHandler sqsMessageHandler = new SqsMessageHandler(amazonSqs);
        sqsMessageHandler.setQueue("queue-one-123");
        sqsMessageHandler.setOutputChannelName("sqsMultiDispatchResultChannel");
        sqsMessageHandler.setFailureChannelName("errorChannel");
        return sqsMessageHandler;
    }


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow queueTwoDispatchFlow(MessageHandler publishToQueueTwoHandler) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("sqsMultiDispatchChannel")
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("errorChannel", "errorChannel"))
                .handle(publishToQueueTwoHandler)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler publishToQueueTwoHandler() {
        final SqsMessageHandler sqsMessageHandler = new SqsMessageHandler(amazonSqs);
        sqsMessageHandler.setQueue("queue-two");
        sqsMessageHandler.setOutputChannelName("sqsMultiDispatchResultChannel");
        sqsMessageHandler.setFailureChannelName("errorChannel");
        return sqsMessageHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorToAggregatorFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("errorChannel")
                .enrichHeaders(
                        h ->
                                h.correlationIdExpression("payload.failedMessage.headers.correlationId")
                                        .headerExpression(
                                                "sequenceSize", "payload.failedMessage.headers.sequenceSize")
                                        .headerExpression("sequenceNumber", "payload.failedMessage.headers.sequenceNumber"))
                .log()
                .channel("sqsMultiDispatchResultChannel")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow dispatchResultAggregationFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("sqsMultiDispatchResultChannel")
                .aggregate(
                        aggregatorSpec ->
                                aggregatorSpec
                                        .outputProcessor(group -> {
                                            final boolean[] hasMultiDispatchErrors = {false};
                                            group.getMessages().forEach(message -> {
                                                    log.info("AGGREGATOR : Group Id -> {} Message -> {}", group.getGroupId(), message );
                                                    hasMultiDispatchErrors[0] = (message instanceof ErrorMessage);
                                            });
                                            return hasMultiDispatchErrors[0];
                                        })
                                        .groupTimeout(10000)
                                        .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true))
                .handle(message -> {
                    if ((Boolean)message.getPayload()) throw new RuntimeException("Publish to one or more queues failed");
                })
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel sqsMultiDispatchChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8))
                .applySequence(true)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel sqsMultiDispatchResultChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }


    @Bean
    public MessageChannel errorChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
    }

}
```

**Update 1:**

Added a `throws` flow as the next handler to aggregator.

```java
.handle(message -> {
                    if ((Boolean)message.getPayload()) throw new RuntimeException("Publish to one or more queues failed");
                })
```

The exception `Publish to one or more queues failed` doesn't seem to propagate to `SqsMessageDrivenAdapter`.

Stack Trace:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Publish to one or more queues failed
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInDeliveryExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:167) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:119) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
...
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Publish to one or more queues failed
    at com.learning.springintegration.sqs.DispatchFlow.lambda$dispatchResultAggregationFlow$6(DispatchFlow.java:108) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

**UPDATE 2 : Removed Aggregator**

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class DispatchFlow {

    private final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs;

    @Bean
    public MessageProducer ingesionQueueConsumer() {
        SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
                new SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(amazonSqs, "ingestion");
        adapter.setVisibilityTimeout(5);
        adapter.setWaitTimeOut(10);
        adapter.setAutoStartup(true);
        adapter.setMaxNumberOfMessages(5);
        adapter.setOutputChannelName("sqsMultiDispatchChannel");
        adapter.setErrorChannelName("errorChannel");
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow queueOneDispatchFlow(MessageHandler publishToQueueOneHandler) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("sqsMultiDispatchChannel")
                .transform(String.class, source-> source.toUpperCase())
                .handle(publishToQueueOneHandler)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler publishToQueueOneHandler() {
        final SqsMessageHandler sqsMessageHandler = new SqsMessageHandler(amazonSqs);
        sqsMessageHandler.setQueue("queue-one-123");
        sqsMessageHandler.setOutputChannelName("successChannel");
        sqsMessageHandler.setFailureChannelName("errorChannel");
        return sqsMessageHandler;
    }


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow queueTwoDispatchFlow(MessageHandler publishToQueueTwoHandler) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("sqsMultiDispatchChannel")
                .transform(String.class, source-> source.toLowerCase())
                .handle(publishToQueueTwoHandler)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler publishToQueueTwoHandler() {
        final SqsMessageHandler sqsMessageHandler = new SqsMessageHandler(amazonSqs);
        sqsMessageHandler.setQueue("queue-two");
        sqsMessageHandler.setOutputChannelName("successChannel");
        sqsMessageHandler.setFailureChannelName("errorChannel");
        return sqsMessageHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow logErrorAndThrow() {

        return IntegrationFlows.from("errorChannel")
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.ERROR, message -> "FAILURE -> " + message)
                .handle(
                        m -> {
                            throw (RuntimeException) (m.getPayload());
                        })
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow logSuccess() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("successChannel")
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, message -> "SUCCESS -> " + message)
                .get();
    }


    @Bean
    public MessageChannel sqsMultiDispatchChannel() {
        return MessageChannels
                .publishSubscribe(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel successChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();

    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel errorChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
    }

}
```

The output

```
2021-06-05 13:01:23.016  INFO 3241 --- [pool-1-thread-3] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : SUCCESS -> GenericMessage [payload=TEST MULTI DISPATCH, headers={aws_messageId=d049c3e4-6ebb-4a1d-a2d7-c3fca36b188d, ApproximateReceiveCount=1, SentTimestamp=1622890877969, aws_receivedQueue=ingestion, Visibility=org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.QueueMessageVisibility@403ef4eb, aws_serviceResult={MD5OfMessageBody: d9e0c5523c40383916fc3253dff37c0c,MD5OfMessageAttributes: f304bbc066f7c3089b860fc2fedb7e22,MessageId: e6650862-bc6e-4170-bf0f-03be45c4f8af,}, id=c64acfd0-0508-d580-7107-5b20efaae729, SenderId=127.0.0.1, lookupDestination=ingestion, aws_receiptHandle=d049c3e4-6ebb-4a1d-a2d7-c3fca36b188d#142a6e3d-cb56-4603-81b7-f16a2ece5fcd, ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp=1622890883003, timestamp=1622890883016}]
2021-06-05 13:01:23.038 ERROR 3241 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : FAILURE -> ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'publishToQueueTwoHandler' for component 'queueTwoDispatchFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/learning/springintegration/sqs/DispatchFlow.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@768ccdc5']; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: The queue does not exist.; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.QueueDoesNotExistException: AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue; see the SQS docs. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue; Request ID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000; Proxy: null), failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=test multi dispatch, headers={aws_messageId=d049c3e4-6ebb-4a1d-a2d7-c3fca36b188d, ApproximateReceiveCount=1, SentTimestamp=1622890877969, aws_receivedQueue=ingestion, Visibility=org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.QueueMessageVisibility@403ef4eb, id=5e8d9e30-0568-fb08-a220-25121c5aa08a, SenderId=127.0.0.1, lookupDestination=ingestion, aws_receiptHandle=d049c3e4-6ebb-4a1d-a2d7-c3fca36b188d#142a6e3d-cb56-4603-81b7-f16a2ece5fcd, ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp=1622890883003, timestamp=1622890882987}], headers={id=ed10c19d-96c6-9ad3-1b19-9ee07064282f, timestamp=1622890883038}]
2021-06-05 13:01:23.041  WARN 3241 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.i.c.MessagePublishingErrorHandler    : Error message was not delivered.

org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'publishToQueueTwoHandler' for component 'queueTwoDispatchFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/learning/springintegration/sqs/DispatchFlow.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@768ccdc5']; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: The queue does not exist.; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.QueueDoesNotExistException: AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue; see the SQS docs. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue; Request ID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000; Proxy: null)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:192) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:65) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `replyChannel` involved with the `SqsMessageDrivenAdapter`. It is one-way listener. So, your `replyChannelExpression("payload.failedMessage.headers.replyChannel")` does not make too much sense. You probably better to think where to send a message after your aggregator...

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that was super quick, unfortunately I edited the question a bit. during that time. I want to throw the exception to `SqsMessageDrivenAdapter` so the `redrive` policy of the queue can kick in

Comment: That’s OK and that’s different . I just try to explain you the reason of that “no replyChannel” error. Will look into your edit a bit later...

Comment: I just realised that I need to add a `throws` flow after aggregation, I will try that first and the come back here and update

Comment: I don't see anything new: you still don't have any output on your aggregator. Do you really need that one in your logic? Do you really need to send error to the aggregator? You may also think about something like re-throwing handler as one more subscriber to that `errorChannel`. As long as you handle errors over there nothing is going to be thrown back to the `SqsMessageDrivenAdapter`. So, you need to do that manually or don't do a `errorChannel` at all!

Comment: Yep! See my last comment: we think alike :smile:

Comment: The `throws` doesn't seem to propagate, refer Update 1 in the question

Comment: Well, I thought about one more subscriber for the `errorChannel`. Looks like you use that aggregator also for happy path...

Comment: The purpose of the `aggregator` for my use case is to log the dispatch results (From `ingestion` to multiple queues) and if dispatch to any 1 queue fails, then the `ingestion` queue `redrive` with DLQ must be triggered to prevent message loss for the failed queue.. Is their another way to achieve this ?

Comment: Do you need to aggregate failures, too?

Comment: I think, I don't need the aggregators now, and also the issue I am facing is not related to aggregators. I have simplified the flow, refer to UPDATE 2 for new flow. This issue is that the exception is not thrown back to `SqsMessageDrivenAdapter` when the output channel of `SqsMessageDrivenAdapter` is a pub/sub channel

Comment: Incase, when I don't use the aggregator, and if dispatch to both the queues fail then both will throw an exception (from the `errorChannel`), that's the reason I created the aggregator (aggregate result of multi dispatch), so per ingestion message, only 1 excepton will be thrown. In short 2 issues - 1) Propagate the exception to `SqsMessageDrivenAdapter` for redrive 2) Throw exception only once in case both `queue-one` and `queue-two` fail

Comment: Yes, you can use an aggregator for that use-case. You collect all the possible results over there (errors and success) and make a decision to throw an exception back after an aggregator examining its result in the next service activator (`.handle()`)

Comment: Throwing the exception from the next `.handle()` does not propagate to the `SqsMessageDrivenAdapter`, see `Update 1` of the question. For now, I am doing a manual `ack` when there are no errors in the aggregated response.